# Kubernetes deploying container in master

Tags: docker, deployment, kubernetes, master-slave

I have set up a kubernetes cluster and is working fine.

As of now, Kubernetes cluster deploying container in the master as well. I dont want this to be happened . Can anybody let me know, how to prevent to deploy container in the master ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want no Pods to be scheduled on the master you will need to [taint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/v1.6/#taint) the master node:

```
kubectl taint nodes nameofmaster dedicated=master:NoSchedule
```

Read up on [taints and tolerations](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/taint-toleration-dedicated.md) to understand the consequences and how to schedule specific Pods on the now tainted master node. To undo use `kubectl taint nodes nameofmaster dedicated-`